# ASP.NET MVC, Bootstrap Tables, get values for each column

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

In ASP.NET MVC, I've an action which takes user input about rows and columns and then it navigates to the action which generates required number of rows and columns based on the user input as shown below:-

Views:

```
<div class="container" style='width:@(240 * Model.Columns.Capacity)px;overflow-y:auto'>
<div class="row">
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <table style='width:100%' class='table table-condensed'>
            <tbody>
                @for (int k = 0; k < Model.Rows.Capacity; k++)
                {
                    <tr>
                        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Columns.Capacity; i++)
                        {
                            <td>
                                @Html.TextBox("name" + k + i, null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                            </td>
                        }
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <input type="submit" name="name" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
    }
</div>
```

And after entering.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxhOM.png

In the post action, I've a form collection in order to get the filled data in the post action using a form collection. In the post action I get the values for each input field using a foreach loop.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Enter(FormCollection form)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < form.Count; i++)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(form[i]);
        }
        return View();
    }
```

I just want to know that how to get all the values of a single column in the post action and get them column by columns, by default it gets the values of horizontally.

Thanks.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBMvY.png

Comment: Are your rows and columns dynamic or is it the same structure every time?

Comment: Its same once it is generated.

Comment: And how are you generating the names of your input fields? Can you show some example markup which is generated?

Comment: You should use a view model with `List<Column> Row` where Column contains `string Value` so you can generate a view that is strongly typed and posts back to your model

Comment: If you use an 2 dimensional array as your viewmodel when generating the table, then post that viewmodel, it will all be populated *auto-magically* for you

Comment: @timothyclifford just updated the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create view models that represent what you want to display/edit

```
public class TableVM
{
  public TableVM()
  {
    Rows = new List<RowVM>();
  }
  public TableVM(int rows, int columns) : this()
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
      Rows.Add(new RowVM(columns));
    }
  }
  public List<string> Headers { get; set; } // for columns headers
  public List<RowVM> Rows { get; set; }
}
public class RowVM
{
  public RowVM()
  {
    Cells = new List<CellVM>();
  }
  public RowVM(int columns) : this()
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
    {
      Cells.Add(new CellVM());
    }
  }
  public List<CellVM> Cells { get; set; }
}
public class CellVM
{
  public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

and in the GET method, initialize a new `TableVM` and return it to the view

```
TableVM model = new TableVM(5, 5); // 5 x 5 grid
model.Headers = new List<string>{ "col 1", "col 2", "col 3", col 4", "col 5" };
return View(model);
```

View

```
@model TableVM
....
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      @foreach(string header in Model.Headers)
      {
        <th>@header</th>
      }
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @for(int r = 0; r < Model.Rows.Count; r++)
    {
      <tr>
        for (int c = 0; c < Model.Rows[r].Cells.Count; c++)
        {
          <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Rows[r].Cells[c].Value</td>
        }
      </tr>
    }
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Then change you POST method to accept the model

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Enter(TableVM model)
```

You can now access each row/column using indexers, for example `model.Rows[1].Cells[2].Value` will return the value of the 3rd column in the second row

Comment: Thanks for the support, I'm about to try your idea please also tell me what if I want in the post action to Iterate through first column, and then second column and so on and so forth. Can you show me the code?

Comment: Lots of ways depending on what your wanting to do - e.g. if your wanted to total the values in the second column `int total = 0; foreach(var row in model.Rows) { total += row.Cells[1].Value; }; (but that assumes the `Value` property is `int`, not `string`)/ I will also update his shortly to show how to add constructors to automate the generation of rows and columns

Comment: See update for simplifying the generation of rows and columns using constructors.

Comment: Thank you very much @Stephen, it works I just need one more thing to know that the way you showed the code works fine for simple text boxes. But is I use form-control class with the TextBoxFor, then it wraps up and doesn't show the horizontal scroll bar and shows for simple text boxes. can you show me that solution?. Thanks

I've done this at the top line of my View while by assigning custom width.

Comment: Sorry, I not sure what your mean. What scroll bar are you referring to (and looking at your images in the question, I can see any scroll bars)

Comment: If we use 20 columns, it shows the horizontal scroll bar on the code you've shown. But the textboxes are of static html not the bootstrap. If you assign the class of the control to form-control then it wraps up (becomes narrower) and horizontal scroll bar disappears. I just want to use form-control with horizontal scroll bar without wrapping. Thanks

Comment: Please also show me how to add title of each columns. Thanks

Comment: Without knowing your css its hard to give you an answer, but you probably need to add a style for the width - e.g. `input[type="textbox"] { width: 100px; }` (or `minwidth`). You probably need to ask a new question including images with and without `class = "form-control"` to better explain the issue and include the css for the textboxes

Comment: See update for example of adding headers. Its not ideal yet, because there are no checks to ensure the numbers of headers matches the number of columns but I'll leave it to you to enhance it.

Comment: Thank you very much, you greatly solved the issues for me. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way would be to post the number of rows and columns back with the input values:

```
<div class="container" style='width:@(240 * Model.Columns.Capacity)px;overflow-y:auto'>
<div class="row">
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <table style='width:100%' class='table table-condensed'>
            <tbody>
                @for (int k = 0; k < Model.Rows.Capacity; k++)
                {
                    <tr>
                        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Columns.Capacity; i++)
                        {
                            <td>
                                @Html.TextBox("name" + k + i, null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                            </td>
                        }
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <input name="rows" type="hidden" value="@Model.Rows.Capacity"/>
        <input name="columns" type="hidden" value="@Model.Columns.Capacity"/>

        <input type="submit" name="name" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
    }
</div>
```

Once you have these, you can use them to work out how many iterations to do and the input names to query:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Enter(FormCollection form)
{
    var data = new List<List<string>>();
    var rows = int.Parse(form["rows"]);
    var columns = int.Parse(form["columns"]);

    for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    {
        var rowData = new List<string>();

        for (var c = 0; c < columns; c++)
        {
            rowData.Add(form[string.Format("name{0}{1}", r, c)]);
        }

        data.Add(rowData);
    }

    return View(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
to get value horizontally you have to put name attribute in your view like
<table class="table table-striped table-advance table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-wg-15">Name</th>
            <th class="col-wg-5 t1_td_per">Allocation Percentage</th>
            <th class="col-wg-5">Allocation</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
 <tbody>
    @{
    foreach (var item in Model.t1_List)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @item.Name
            </td>
            <td class="t1_td_per">
                <input type="text" name="t1_txtper-@item.BId" id="t1_txtper-@item.BId" value="@item.AllocationPercentage" class="t1_AllocationPer" maxlength="20" placeholder="Allocation Percentage" style="text-align:right;" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="t1_txtamt-@item.BId" id="t1_txtamt-@item.BId" value="@item.AllocationAmount" class="t1_AllocationAmt decimalval" maxlength="20" placeholder="Allocation" style="text-align:right;" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    }
</tbody>
</table>

and then at the time of post or in action method you can get this as 

  Dictionary<decimal, decimal> _d_amt = new Dictionary<decimal, decimal>();
  Dictionary<decimal, decimal> _d_per = new Dictionary<decimal, decimal>();

            foreach (var key in _frm.AllKeys)
            {
                if (key.ParseString().Contains("t1_txtamt-"))
                {
                    decimal _val = _frm[key].ParseString().ParseDecimal();
                    decimal _id = key.Replace("t1_txtamt-", "").ParseString().ParseDecimal();

                    _d_amt.Add(_id, _val);
                }
                else if (key.ParseString().Contains("t1_txtper-"))
                {
                    decimal _val = _frm[key].ParseString().ParseDecimal();
                    decimal _id = key.Replace("t1_txtper-", "").ParseString().ParseDecimal();

                    _d_per.Add(_id, _val);
                }
            }

            foreach (var item in _model.t1_List)
            {
                AllocationClass _litem = new AllocationClass();
                _litem.BId = item.BId;
                _litem.Name = item.Name;
                _litem.AllocationPercentage = (from p in _d_per where p.Key == item.BId select p.Value).FirstOrDefault().ParseDecimal();
                _litem.AllocationAmount = (from p in _d_amt where p.Key == item.BId select p.Value).FirstOrDefault().ParseDecimal();

                _list.Add(_litem);
            }
```