# Count total sum of the same product name from different departments in my ASP.NET MVC Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

Is this posible to organize Car Status from different cities? I want to count total amount of cars of the same car name by a group using LINQ (using Query or method syntax)..? My table name "Cars" looks like Image below:
I think I have problem already how to create viewmodel and get departments name .... and then formulating LINQ code...
[image]

Trying to do like this but geting wrong result:
I'am trying to do like following but givs me wrong Result

```
    public class Car
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CarName { get; set; } 
        public int DeptId { get; set; }
        public int Status { get; set; }
    }

    public class Department
    {
        public int DeptId { get; set; }
        public string DeptName { get; set; }

    }

    public class CarViewModel
    {
        public string CarName { get; set; } ??? // Is this right?
        public Department DeptName { get; set; }
        public int Status { get; set; }
    }




 [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult> GetTotalCars()
        {
            using (context)
            {

                 var summary = (from c in context.Cars
                  group c by new { c.CarName, c.DeptId } into grp
                  join d in context.Departments on grp.Key.DeptId equals d.Id
                  select new CarViewModel { CarName = grp.Key.CarName, 
                                            DeptName =  d.DeptName, 
                                            Status = grp.Sum(s => s.Status) })
        .ToListAsync();

                return await summary;

            }

        }
```

I would be grateful if you guys would help me.

Comment: Your view model is not correct to represent what you want in the view. You would need a model with a property for the car name, and a collection property to represent the table columns.

Comment: @StephenMuecke thank you. I knew it was something wrong with my ViewModel. Do youhave any idea how to write my CarViewModel. I changed public Department DeptName { get; set; } to public String DeptName { get; set; } , but givs me another error...

Comment: You need a view model that represents the table you want to display, so that you can loop through objects to generate a table row, and a nested loop to generate objects that represent table cells within a row. Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34197582/asp-net-mvc-bootstrap-tables-get-values-for-each-column/34197963#34197963) for an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you could get totals per car name and per department, as your view model hints:

```
 var summary = (from c in Cars
                  group c by new { c.CarName, c.DeptId } into grp
                  join d in Departments on grp.Key.DeptId equals d.Id
                  select new CarViewModel { CarName = grp.Key.CarName, 
                                            DeptName =  d.DeptName, 
                                            Status = grp.Sum(s => s.Status) })
                .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, Shall this  Status = grp.Sum(s => s.Status) } give me Total of Volvo , Toyoyta and Ford cars? if you look my last PartiellView table that  I want to reach the result. I think I have to add one property in my viewModel class int total. Or maybe Status is like Total of Volvo cars, Toyota cars and Ford cars of every department? Thank you again

Comment: this givs me error DeptName =  d.DeptName. Error message "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'Cars.Models.Department'"

Comment: @HelenTekie Query will give you totals per car and department, as it shown in your spreadsheet. For ex. It will contain following data: Volvo, New York, 10; Toyota, Berlin, 6; etc. You are getting the error, because I thought, that you need department name, not Department object in your CarViewModel class. To overcome this you need instantiate Department object in the query and populated properly, if you need actual Department object, not its name.

Comment: @fatherOfWine  It's true I need departmentname, but I don't know how to formulate my CarViewModel.. I knew it was something wrong with my ViewModel. Do youhave any idea how to write my CarViewModel. I changed public Department DeptName { get; set; } to public String DeptName { get; set; } , but givs me another error...

Comment: @HelenTeckie  Yes, you need to change DeptName property type to string and that should fix the query. What error did you get?

Comment: I get this error : Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Cars.Models.CarViewModel >' to 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult' As you see I have edited my HttpGet Action.

Comment: I mean In this section => "return await summary" I get this error : Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Cars.Models.CarViewModel >' to 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult' As you see I have edited my HttpGet Action

Comment: @HelenTeckie Well, you get this error, because you need  pass data structure you generated to the appropriate view to be shown. You have to create a view(or use existing one) which would handle your generated list of CarViewModels and convert it to the html table(I presume) of your choice inside the view.

Comment: thank you now I don not get any error. But by any reasen I do not see the results either. But it is something I have to learn more about Views maybe. But thank you very much for your help. It seems litle complicated.