# MVC Create Table from Dictionary<string, List<MyModel>> Values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dictionary, razor, asp.net-core

Given a dictionary in the following format, I want to output in a desire forat as shown below:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new Dictionary<string, List<MyModel>>
    {
        {
                "Heading1",
                new List<MyModel>()
                {
                    new MyModel() {MyKey = "Foo", MyValue = "Value1"},
                    new MyModel() {MyKey = "Bar", MyValue = "Value2"},
                    new MyModel() {MyKey = "Baz", MyValue = "Value3"}
                }
            },
            {
                "Heading2",
                new List<MyModel>()
                {
                    new MyModel() {MyKey = "Foo", MyValue = "Value4"},
                    new MyModel() {MyKey = "Bar", MyValue = "Value5"}
                }
            },
            {
                "Heading3",
                new List<MyModel>()
                {
                    new MyModel() {MyKey = "Foo", MyValue = "Value6"},
                    new MyModel() {MyKey = "Baz", MyValue = "Value7"}
                }
            }
        };

    return View(model);
}
```

Where MyModel is just a simple class:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string MyKey { get; set; }

    public string MyValue { get; set; }
}
```

I want to output information in the following format:

[image]

However currently what I have tried in the view does not display correctly:

```
@model Dictionary<string, List<MyModel>>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h2>Results</h2>

<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Keys)
        {
            <th>@item</th>
        }
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    @foreach (var list in Model.Values)
    {
        <tr>
            @foreach (var item in list)
            {
                <td>@item.MyKey</td>

                <td>@item.MyValue</td>
            }
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I display data in desired format?

Comment: Your `Dictionary<string, List<MyModel>>` property has no relationship at all to what you want to display in the view. You need a view model similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34197582/asp-net-mvc-bootstrap-tables-get-values-for-each-column/34197963#34197963)

Comment: Do you have to use a dictionary?

Comment: I can give you a solution this way as well but dictionaries arent meant to be used this way, I suggest a list of class and using LINQ on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model is extremely different from the data you need to show in your view. The first issue is that you are trying to model a table (in html a collection of rows) grouping values by Columns.

I strongly advise you to change your model, but if you want to keep it as is, I'll give you a solution (even if inefficient):

```
var columns = new []{""}.Concat(model.Keys);
// columns names with the first empty column

var rows = model
    .SelectMany(c => c.Value.Select(v => new {c.Key, v.MyKey, v.MyValue}))
    // get single cells of table

    .GroupBy(v => v.MyKey, v => v)
    // group by row name

    .Select(row => new[] {row.Key}
                       .Concat(model.Keys.Select(c =>
                            row.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Key == c)?.MyValue)));
    // create row with row name as first value

var vm = new { Columns = columns, Rows = rows };
return View(vm);
```

You will then be able to show your records as you need:

```
@model dynamic

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h2>Results</h2>

<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Columns)
        {
            <th>@item</th>
        }
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    @foreach (var row in Model.Rows)
    {
        <tr>
            @foreach (var cell in row)
            {    
                <td>@cell</td>
            }
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```